# Pandas add values from dictionary iteratively

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

We have the following dummy dataframe that scrapes many messages:

```
temp = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['I am feeling very well',],['It is hard to believe this happened',],
                              ['What is love?',], ['Amazing day today',]]),
                            columns = ['message',])
```

Output:

```
     message            
0    I hate the weather today
1    It is hard to believe this happened
2    What is love
3    Amazing day today
```

I iterate through each individual message in order to extract the sentiment from them

```
for i in temp.message:
    x = model.predict(i, 'roberta')
```

where **x** is a dictionary of the form:

```
x = {
    "Love" : 0.0931,
    "Hate" : 0.9169,
    }
```

How can I add all of the values in the dictionary to the data frame while iterating through each?

```
for i in temp.message:
    x = model.predict(i, 'roberta')
    y = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(x,orient='index')
    y = y.T
    # what would the next step be?
```

Maybe creating the columns with null values and then creating a left join on every iteration on the message column would be a plausible solution? What would be most optimal?

Expected output:

```
     message                                   Love           Hate
0    I hate the weather today                  0.0931         0.9169
1    It is hard to believe this happened       0.444          0.556
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't try to assign while looping, collect in a list and assign/join in the end:

```
df = temp.join(pd.json_normalize([model.predict(i, 'roberta')
                                  for i in temp.message]))

# OR
df = temp.join(pd.DataFrame([model.predict(i, 'roberta')
                             for i in temp.message]))
```

Example:

```
                               message    Love    Hate
0               I am feeling very well  0.0931  0.9169
1  It is hard to believe this happened  0.0931  0.9169
2                        What is love?  0.0931  0.9169
3                    Amazing day today  0.0931  0.9169
```

Comment: Elegant solution. Can you explain the difference or different use cases for json normalize vs dataframe?

Comment: @DarknessPlusPlus here it will do the same thing, `json_normalize` is a bit more flexible if the input is variable but also probably slower

Comment: Another advantage might be to feed an output from `apply`: `pd.json_normalize(temp['message'].apply(lambda x: model.predict(x, 'roberta')))`

Comment: is there a reason why this method would return NaN values? I checked the list comprehension and it works fine. It returns all the values. But when doing temp.join then on the real database, it returns NaN everywhere? Works on the dummy data tho. What could be the issue?

Comment: You probably don't have a range index. Then use `df = temp.join(pd.DataFrame([model.predict(i, 'roberta') for i in temp.message], index=temp.index))` or use the above comment's `apply` variant that will maintain the original index: `df = temp.join(pd.json_normalize(temp['message'].apply(lambda x: model.predict(x, 'roberta'))))`

Answer (score 1):

You can create columns with `np.NaN` values initially and update when necessary

```py
temp = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['I am feeling very well',],['It is hard to believe this happened',],
                              ['What is love?',], ['Amazing day today',]]),
                            columns = ['message',])
temp['Love'] = np.nan
temp['Hate'] = np.nan
```

Then update the values in the loop -

```py
for i, message in enumerate(temp.message):
    x = model.predict(message, 'Roberta')
    temp.loc[i].Love = x["Love"]
    temp.loc[i].Hate= x["Hate"]
```